# Modified Linked List in C Programming

Tags: c, linked-list

So I have got a linked list and I'm trying to make the linked list in reverse as I add new nodes to it. So my linked list holds two pieces of data and a pointer to the next object. When I add a new node, I want the node to point to the current linked list. I've tried doing it so that I point the current list's next pointer to the current Linked list and then then change the data in the current linked list but I can't get it to work.

Below is my code and what I've tried. It's just giving me a circular linked list which is pointing to itself.

```
struct Node {
    void *data;
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};   

struct Node *list;

void create() {
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
}

void add(*data, int value){
    if (list->value != 0){
        list->next = list;
    }

    list->data = mem_address /* memory address of some item */;
    list->value = value;
}
```

So the first node gets added in correctly but then once I add the second node, it's just a Linked list with the value of next pointing to itself and essentially a circular linked list. Could someone help me out please.

Here's an example to make it a bit clearer.

```
create();
add(pointer, 12);
add(pointer2, 22);
```

so it would look like this;

> ```
> +-------+----------------+
> | Data  | 0x7fecfbd4103c |
> +-------+----------------+
> | value |      22        |
> +-------+----------------+
> | next  |                |
> +-------+----------------+
>
> +-------+----------------+
> | Data  | 0x7fdb9904a03c |
> +-------+----------------+
> | value |      12        |
> +-------+----------------+
> | next  |     NULL       |
> +-------+----------------+
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
struct Node {
    void *data;
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};   

struct Node *list=NULL; 

void create(){
   // list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

   //Does nothing. Not required.
}

void add(void *data, int value){
    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->data=data;
    node->value=value;
    node->next=list;
    list=node;
}

void destroy(){
    while(list!=NULL){
        struct Node* next=list->next;
        free(list);
        list=next;
    }
}
```

The list is initialised as empty. So you don't need your `create()` function.
But you should call `destroy()` when you've finished with the list.
If that's at the end of the program you don't really need to call it - the environment will reclaim the memory. However it is good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need two base pointers (list and list_end)

That way you arrange for 'list' to point at the first entry in the chain and 'list_end' points at the last and you can add new nodes at either end.

If you're having trouble keeping track of the pointers, bits of paper and string with buttons on the end might help :-)

Also, beware, that you should make sure that you either clear the memory returned by malloc or always set all the fields. (ie: set 'next' to zero)

Hmmm; you do have to do a malloc for each list node too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your `add()` method as follows . And also your `add()` method need a pointer type of `struct Node`(at least some type) else it will throw a compiler error

```
void add(struct Node *data, int value); // Corrected add method prototype
```

And corrected `add()` method

```
void add(struct Node *data, int value){
       data->value = value;
       data->next=list;
       list=data;
}
```

A working example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
void *data;
int value;
struct Node *next;
};   

struct Node *list;

void add(struct Node *data, int value);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    // Defining END node
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list->value = -1;
    list->next=NULL;

    // Adding data
    struct Node* temp=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));     
    add(temp,12);

    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));     
    add(temp,20);

    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));       
    add(temp,22);

    // Use Head to walk through the linked list
    temp=list;

   // Walk through it and verify order
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d \n",temp->value);
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void add(struct Node *data, int value){
       data->value = value;
       data->next=list;
       list=data; // list will always be the HEAD
}
```

Output :

```
20
12
-1
```